# convert the google map V2 to V3 code for set the markers in the google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am new to V3. I am converting the V2 code to V3. In the below function, projection value is not coming. From that projection they are used fromLatLngToPixel and fromPixelToLatLng. Instead of that two function, how to use in V3 google maps. containsLatLng, getLatLang also tell how to use in V3 google maps. Please help.

```
  function flagContainedMarkers (){
// Iterate through the markers and only set makeVisible to
// true if the marker is inside the map bounds & padding
var pad = this.borderPadding;

var zoom        = this.map.getZoom();
var projection  = this.map.getCurrentMapType().getProjection();
var bounds      = this.map.getBounds();

var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
sw = projection.fromLatLngToPixel(sw, zoom);
sw = new google.maps.Point(sw.x-pad, sw.y+pad);
sw = projection.fromPixelToLatLng(sw, zoom, true);

var ne = bounds.getNorthEast()
ne = projection.fromLatLngToPixel(ne, zoom);
ne = new google.maps.Point(ne.x+pad, ne.y-pad);
ne = projection.fromPixelToLatLng(ne, zoom, true);

var paddedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

for (var i = this.markers.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var marker = this.markers[i];
    marker.makeVisible = paddedBounds.containsLatLng(marker.getLatLng()) ? true:false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, Any body can please help for the migration of V2 to V3.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some replacements in your code...try this ...

```
function flagContainedMarkers (){ // Iterate through the markers and only set makeVisible to true if the marker is inside the map bounds & padding
   var pad = this.borderPadding;
   var zoom        = this.map.getZoom();
   var projection  = this.map.getProjection();
   var bounds      = this.map.getBounds();

   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
       sw = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw, zoom);
       sw = new google.maps.Point(sw.lat()-pad, sw.lng()+pad);
       sw = projection.fromPointToLatLng(sw, zoom, true);

   var ne = bounds.getNorthEast()
       ne = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(ne, zoom);
       ne = new google.maps.Point(ne.lat()+pad, ne.lng()-pad);
       ne = projection.fromPointToLatLng(ne, zoom, true);

    var paddedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    for (var i = this.markers.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
       var marker = this.markers[i];
       marker.makeVisible = paddedBounds.contains(marker.position()) ? true:false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. In that code sw.x value as coming as "undefined". So, i alert it the sw.x-pad value is coming as NaN. Because of this I cant proceed to next steps. Please Help!!!

Comment: Hi, Anybody, Please reply for the above comment.

Comment: I edited my answer...check it...I forgot to replace **sw.x/ne.x** with **sw.lat()/ne.lat()** and **sw.y/ne.y** with **sw.lng()/ne.lng()**....